# HM-10 discovery issue

Tags: bluetooth

i am not able to detect any android device on my bluetooth HM-10 module which is connected to arduino. i am able to see my bluetooth module on my android phone. but i want to see android phones on arduino serial monitor for that i used AT+DISC? command. it shows AT+DISCS and than AT+DISCE with a 2 second interval. help me to solve the issue
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The HM-10 is a BLE-only device.

Android phones do not normally transmit BLE advertisements, so there is normally nothing about an Android phone for it to discover.

The exception would be if you have software on a late Android version with the capability, which you have set up to intentionally transmit BLE advertisements, or else if software you put on your Android phone is actively responding to advertisements you had the HM-10 transmit.

Essentially, you are expecting something that his not normal behavior, but will only be achieved by adding your software on *both* devices.

Comment: Good answer, it's like my laptop seeing all wifi connections. But my accesspoint not seeing all (unconnected) devices. It depends on which device is the "searcher" and which is "advertising itself". In practice, most devices don't do both.

Answer (score -1):

Detecting the physical Bluetooth layer is likely different from detecting the underlying protocol.  So it might be that the Arduino code is waiting until it sees a specific Bluetooth protocol.  I am guessing that it wants to use a serial Bluetooth protocol (as oppose to music or some other protocol).  You have not given enough details to determine if this is the problem.  However, I would next test your devices / hardware by loading up what is assumed to be working code on both your Android and your Arduino to test the connection.  The code in [this project](https://github.com/danasf/hm10-android-arduino) looks promising:

Comment: is there any way such that i can make the protocol compatible since my hm-10 is getting detected on various mobile devices. my project requirement is such that i have to detect the mac id of other phones near the range of hm-10.

Comment: MAC is a feature of the phone's WIFI. I wouldn't expect the MAC information to be available on the Bluetooth port without an application on each phone specifically written to do tHis.

Comment: @st2000 MAC addresses are not confined to wifi, Bluetooth has its own as well.